# How to get the relative filename to a specific directory?

Tags: c#, relative-path

I have a method which is doing a file copy. The 'root' is specified by the user on the command line, which I sanitize with `Path.GetFullPath(input)`.

I need to get the path of the file relative to that root, so the following cases would return:

```
Root        FilePath                    Return
y:\         y:\temp\filename1.txt       temp\filename1.txt
y:\dir1     y:\dir1\dir2\filename2.txt  dir2\filename2.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
var relative = new Uri(rootPath).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(filePath));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx

Comment: that turns it into "../" which doesn't even seem to be related?

Comment: rootPath = y:\ , filePath = y:\2010-05\DSC_154.JGP

Comment: @esac: Sorry; I got the parameters wrong.  Swap the Uris and it should work.

Comment: May want to make rootPath => a replacement from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20405965/420667 since this one doesn't pass test 2 since the rootPath is missing a trailing backslash.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s1 = "y:\\";
string s2 = "y:\\temp\filename1.txt";
Console.WriteLine(s2.Substring(s1.Length)); \\ Outputs temp\filename1.txt
```

Hope this helps

Might want to call a .Trim() as well to ensure removing trailing \ characters or the like.

Comment: Nah I meant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx for the actual method with prototype and all that.. But if you wanted just to do it to one side it would be TrimStart for this... a filename cant have \ in them, but it might be at the start of the path for sub-sub folder paths.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath( filePath ).Substring( rootPath.Length )
```

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath( filePath ).Substring( System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(rootPath).Length )` would be safer I think - convert both strings to system paths before assuming that the length of the rootPath is identical in both strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
string relativePath = Path.GetFullPath(input).Replace(rootPath, "");
```