# How to ensure there is trailing directory separator in paths?

Tags: c#, .net, path

I'm having an issue with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Sometimes the path ends with '', sometimes it doesn't and I can't find a reason for this.

It would be fine if I was using `Path.Combine` but I want to do `Directory.GetParent` and it yields different results.

My current solution is:

```
var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
if (!baseDir.EndsWith("\\")) baseDir += "\\";
```

Is there another way to get the parent directory of the application?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's like that, just keep your hack.

In *plain* Win32 there is an helper function [PathAddBackslash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that. Just be consistent with directory separator: check `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` instead of hard-code `\`.

**UPDATE**: if you're targeting any recent.NET version (Core 3.0 and above) then you could use some newer functions:

```cs
string PathAddDirectorySeparator(string path)
{
    if (path is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

    path = path.TrimEnd();

    if (Path.EndsInDirectorySeparator(path))
        return path;

    return path + GetDirectorySeparatorUsedInPath();

    char GetDirectorySeparatorUsedInPath()
    {
        if (path.Contains(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
            return Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar;
       
        return Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
   }
}
```

If you decide you do not want to support `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` and you do not mind the extra string allocation then consider using `Path.TrimEndingDirectorySeparator(path)` instead of simply `path.TrimEnd('\\')`.

---

**Original answer**: something like this (please note there is not a serious error checking):

```
string PathAddBackslash(string path)
{
    // They're always one character but EndsWith is shorter than
    // array style access to last path character. Change this
    // if performance are a (measured) issue.
    string separator1 = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    string separator2 = Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    // Trailing white spaces are always ignored but folders may have
    // leading spaces. It's unusual but it may happen. If it's an issue
    // then just replace TrimEnd() with Trim(). Tnx Paul Groke to point this out.
    path = path.TrimEnd();

    // Argument is always a directory name then if there is one
    // of allowed separators then I have nothing to do.
    if (path.EndsWith(separator1) || path.EndsWith(separator2))
        return path;

    // If there is the "alt" separator then I add a trailing one.
    // Note that URI format (file://drive:\path\filename.ext) is
    // not supported in most .NET I/O functions then we don't support it
    // here too. If you have to then simply revert this check:
    // if (path.Contains(separator1))
    //     return path + separator1;
    //
    // return path + separator2;
    if (path.Contains(separator2))
        return path + separator2;

    // If there is not an "alt" separator I add a "normal" one.
    // It means path may be with normal one or it has not any separator
    // (for example if it's just a directory name). In this case I
    // default to normal as users expect.
    return path + separator1;
}
```

Why *so much* code? Primary because if user enter `/windows/system32` you don't want to get `/windows/system32\` but `/windows/system32/`, devil is in the details...

To put everything together in a nicer self-explicative form:

```
string PathAddBackslash(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

    path = path.TrimEnd();

    if (PathEndsWithDirectorySeparator())
        return path;

    return path + GetDirectorySeparatorUsedInPath();

    bool PathEndsWithDirectorySeparator()
    {
        if (path.Length == 0)
            return false;

        char lastChar = path[path.Length - 1];
        return lastChar == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
            || lastChar == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar;
    }

    char GetDirectorySeparatorUsedInPath()
    {
        if (path.Contains(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
            return Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar;
    
        return Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    }
}
```

URI format `file://` is not handled even if it may seem so. The *right thing* is again to do what the other .NET I/O functions do: do not handle this format (and possibly throw an exception).

As alternative you're always able to import Win32 function:

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", 
    EntryPoint = "PathAddBackslashW",
    SetLastError = True,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr PathAddBackslash(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]StringBuilder lpszPath);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I would use the alternative. Although its interesting, a developer would not be sure about what the code is doing.

Comment: @pitermarx actually we're not sure even about what FileCopy does! A _system_ function IMO is always a good choice, at least it'll handle any change for you (and it'll always respect its contract: to add a trailing backslash). Well not always they're perfect solution, of course...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Windows allows leading spaces in file/directory names, so the `Trim()` call does no good. (It probably also allows trailing spaces, but at least cmd.exe doesn't seem to support them, and I haven't done further testing, so I cannot be sure.)
Personally I'd just completely remove the Trim call. After all it's not the functions responsibility to "fix" broken paths.
Also I would change the "which one to add" logic to just replicate the last seperator in the string (I've seen file:// paths that use backslaches in the rest of the string).

Comment: @PaulGroke you're right about leading spaces (updating answer). URI format isn't allowed in most .NET I/O functions then it's not an issue (when handling URIs with file:// you must extract path by yourself).

Comment: Doesn't your first version transform `file://drive:\path\filename.ext` to `file://drive:\path\filename.ext/`, and the second version creates `file://drive:\path\filename.ext\`? I.e., if there mixed separators, does the first version not prefer the alternative separator, whereas the second version prefers the standard one?

Comment: @SebastianMach yes, I wrote it in a comment: URI format isn't supported (as in most of .NET I/O functions). _Fix_ is also there in the same comment: invert the check (and `file://drive:\path1\path2` will be`file://drive:\path1\path2\ `. Second version already does like that. Note, however, that there are more corner cases to consider (what about `file://path`?) then the _right thing_ is simply to do what .NET libraries do and IGNORE that format).

Answer (score 72):

You can easily ensure the behaviour you desire by using [TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                  .TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
```

To be optimally efficient (by avoiding extra allocations), check that the string doesn't end with a `\` before making changes, since you won't always need to:

```
const string sepChar = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
const string altChar = Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
if (!baseDir.EndsWith(sepChar) && !baseDir.EndsWith(altChar))
{
    baseDir += sepChar;
}
```

Comment: To make it cross platform you could replace the `"\\"` with `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`

Comment: @Rots: The `TrimEnd` call should include `AltDirectorySeparatorChar` as well

Comment: Slightly more terse syntax using a ternary operator:  

`var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`  

`baseDir = baseDir.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()) ? baseDir : baseDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;`

Answer (score 7):

I often use

```
path = Path.Combine(path, "x");
path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 1);
```

Or, if I needed this more than once or twice in the same project, I'd probably use a helper function like this:

```
string EnsureTerminatingDirectorySeparator(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

    int length = path.Length;
    if (length == 0)
        return "." + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;

    char lastChar = path[length - 1];
    if (lastChar == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || lastChar == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
        return path;

    int lastSep = path.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar });
    if (lastSep >= 0)
        return path + path[lastSep];
    else
        return path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get cross platform support one can use this snippet:

```
using System.IO;

// Your input string.
string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

// Get the absolut path from it (in case ones input is a relative path).
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(baseDir);

// Check for ending slashes, remove them (if any)
// and add a cross platform slash at the end.
string result = fullPath
                    .TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
                    + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
```

As a method:

```
private static string GetFullPathWithEndingSlashes(string input)
{
    string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(input);

    return fullPath
        .TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

Or as an extension method:

```
public static string GetFullPathWithEndingSlashes(this string input)
{
    return Path.GetFullPath(input)
        .TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
        + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of .NET Core 3.0, [`Path.EndsInDirectorySeparator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.endsindirectoryseparator?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_EndsInDirectorySeparator_System_String_) can be used:

```
string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

if (!Path.EndsInDirectorySeparator(baseDir))
{
    baseDir += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

For [Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c636bbdc8a2d393d07c0e9407a4f8923ba1a21cb/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/PathInternal.Unix.cs#L26-L32), it checks if the last `char` is `'/'`.

For [Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c636bbdc8a2d393d07c0e9407a4f8923ba1a21cb/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/PathInternal.Windows.cs#L300-L303) it checks if the last `char` is a literal `'\'` or `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the C# **Path** library, there is a method named **TrimEndingDirectorySeparator**, give your path to the method, if any directory seperator exist end of your path it will trimed, no matter your path is virtual or physical, then instead of using old way to make path string with **String.Format** use C# **$** key, if you have to use **/** seperator in your path simply mix $ and @ as like as below example.

```
var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

string finalPath = $@"{Path.TrimEndingDirectorySeparator(baseDir)}/"
```

Comment: Nice simple solution if you know what format the path should be in i.e. if you know which direction your slash needs to be - some of the other solutions are longer but give a bit more flexibility/adaptability in that regard.  Also just to be clear to others, this is only available in .NET Core 3.0 and .NET 5.0 onwards https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.trimendingdirectoryseparator?view=net-5.0.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Path.Combine anyway then

```
var result = Path.Combine(basepath, subpath, " ").Trim();
```

might be a short solution instead of this very long `TrimEndingDirectorySeparator`.
Note the Space as last parameter.

Comment: Why downvoted? Works as expected. Even Path.Combine(basepath, " ").Trim(); will do the job.